# TextFormField validator The argument type 'dynamic Function()' can't be assigned to the

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

**i am try to make custom widget TextFormField,
but the validator: validator, show error**

*The argument type 'dynamic Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
dynamic Function() validator
package:store/widgets/mytextformfield.dart*

mytextformfield.dart  <<< file widget TextFormField

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() validator;
  final bool obserText;
  final String name;

  const MyTextFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.obserText,
    required this.validator,
    required this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: obserText,
      **validator: validator,**
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: name,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

on login.dart

```
MyTextFormField(
      obserText: obserText,
      name: "Email",
          validator: (value) {
          if (value == "") {
         return "Please Fill Email";
        } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value!)) {
          return "Email is Invaild";
        }
      return "";
      },
     ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator must have a parameter and return null if the value doesn't have any error, and return a String to show error if the value doesn't valid.

```
     TextFormField(
        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
```

Comment: i know what you mean , but i will use this in anther file called login.dart , and i follow tut on YouTube and this work with him , i will edit my post check what code i mean to use

Answer (score 0):

your `myTextFormField.dart` has issues in:

> final Function() validator;

change it to

> final String? Function(String?)? validator;

a validator function simply expects a nullable string, and returns a nullable string

and in validator, instead of returning an empty string, return `null`, like:

```dart
validator: (value) {
  if (value == "") {
    return "Please Fill Email";
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value!)) {
    return "Email is Invaild";
  }
  return null;
}
```

returning null means that the field is valid